# Как выбрать тег, если условие выбора в другом соседнем теге

Tags: python-3.x, beautiful-soup, table, tag

есть такая таблица в html документе:

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr class="type">
        <td>this data is not needed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>   
    <tr class="type">
        <td>this data is not needed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    
    ...

    <tr class="type">
        <td>I need this data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>   
    <tr class="type">
        <td>I need this data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    ...
    <tr class="one">
        some data
    </tr>
    
    ...
</tbody>
```

Нужно вытащить данные из тегов `<tr class="one">`, если они находятся под тегом `<tr class="type">`, внутри которого есть текст "I need this data".
Проблема в том, что все теги tr находятся на одном уровне и их может быть различное количество.
Как обратиться к нужным данным я не представляю.

Comment: Вы можете выбрать вообще абсолютно все tr-теги с классом `one` (описано тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class), если вам другое не важно, в ином случае, опишите вопрос более детально и кейсы, которые вы хотите получить и вам обязательно помогут.

Comment: Можете воспользоваться pandas, табличные данные на раз щелкает. Табличные данные имеют четкую структуру, если увидете эту структуру вы познаете вселенную :)

Comment: Сергей, означает ли ваш коммент, что силами bs4 вытащить нужные данные не получиться? И если это так, может быть есть пример как правильно прочитать и передать данные в pandas. Насколько я понял, pandas будет работать с каким-либо списком, как правильно организовать этот список?

Comment: Borislav, в тегах <tr class="one"> находится идентичная по структуре информация. Если я буду искать нужную информацию простым перебором по всем тегам  <tr class="one">, будет обработана лишняя информация, и это может привести к ошибочному результату работы всей проги. Как я писал выше, нужно вытащить данные из тегов <tr class="one">, если они находятся под тегом <tr class="type">, внутри которого есть текст "I need this data". Если у вас есть решение, пожалуйста сообщите.

Answer (score 0):

Все было просто, по крайней мере в моем случае)

Мое решение:

```
for x in local_soup.find('table').find_all('tr'):
    if 'I need this data' in x.text:
        key = 1
    if 'some data' in x.text and key == 1:
        print(x.text)
```